# Unable to Register Service Worker in React App

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I have created one other component with the name of counter and imported  into the index.js but while registering the service worker; it says "
Attempted import error: './serviceWorker' does not contain a default export (imported as 'registerServiceWorker')."

so i am trying to learn react for my new project through new videos on youtube but while implementing the react i found this error and i am feeling stucked

```
import  React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';

import App from './App';

import registerServiceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

import Counter from './components/counter';


ReactDOM.render(<Counter/>. document.getElementById("root"));

export default registerServiceWorker;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Counter extends Component{
    state={}

    render(){

//        React.createElement
        return <h1>Hello Worlds</h1>
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you importing it just to export it again? Have you tried `import { register } from './serviceWorker';`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55858569/create-react-app-shows-serviceworker-js-and-not-the-registerserviceworker-that-a/55868413#55868413 (which was asked later actually)