# Create React App shows serviceWorker.js and not the registerServiceWorker that a lot of tutorials show

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, service-worker, create-react-app

When I figured I would use Visual Studio Code to get a new React JS application started with learning it etc.. I ran across Microsoft site https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/reactjs-tutorial  In which this shows to

```
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
```

Meanwhile, there doesn't exist,  when I create a new react app it has an index.js file with

```
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
// 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

1. I don't like learning something that is outdated /deprecated so quickly … Is there a much better up to date place to figure out what I am supposed to do to be learning and productively engaged with React JS?
2. Seems that `registerServiceWorker();` was common but is this completely outdated?   [What does registerServiceWorker do in React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953732/what-does-registerserviceworker-do-in-react-js)
3. I want to really just get into calling Restful endpoints of web api, what is a good place to do find best practices to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The serviceWorker support is a part of Create React App (the CLI tool, not React itself). Its [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) are a great place for up-to-date information:

> switching `serviceWorker.unregister()` to `serviceWorker.register()` will opt you in to using the service worker.

As for learning React, while there are a number of great tutorials out there, you can rely on the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) to always reflect the latest version.

React, being just a view library, doesn't prescribe a standard way to make HTTP requests. You can use [any popular request library](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) or just plain old [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), and React will play nice with it.